# Vampires in space

Tags: story-identification, novella, space-opera

I remember reading a novella in an old sci-fi anthology about vampires in space from what they call "the golden age of sci-fi".

It was NOT *Blindsight* by Watts (loved that one), or the choose your own adventure book, or Colin Wilson's novel *The Space Vampires* (loved the movie adaptation). Last month I found a copy of the old anthology I thought it was in, Boucher's *A Treasury of Great Science Fiction*, but it wasn't in that.

It had a sort of A.E. van Vogt feel to it, but it wasn't *Space Beagle*. One of the main vampires was female, reminded me a bit of Olivia Presteign. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't make out that last part; [where were they, again?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1Sq1Nr58hM)

Answer (score 7):

A story with a definite van Vogt-ian feel (after all, it was written by van Vogt) is *[Asylum](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46531)*, first published in Astounding in May 1942, and later anthologised in *[Away and Beyond](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37671)*, a collection of van Vogt's short stories.

It indeed deals with space vampires coming to Earth, to conquer it and harvest our blood. The vampires are a husband and wife pair: the wife, Merla, may be the female character you recall. From a review on [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2981258-away-and-beyond):

> Jeel and Merla, a bickering husband-and-wife team of a race called
> the Dreegh, arrive on Earth, famished unto death. They thus begin to
> do what they do best: suck the blood out of humans and, by kissing
> them on the mouth, drain all the electrical energy out of their
> bodies. These homicides, the first on Earth in 27 years (!), capture
> the attention of newspaper reporter Bill Leigh, who eventually becomes
> a pawn not just of the Dreegh invaders, but also of the Dreegh's
> enemy, the so-called Galactic observer who secretly resides on our
> fair planet. The story culminates in the depths of space, on a meteor
> base near the Jovian moon Europa, where Jeel and Merla are endeavoring
> to kill the Earth scientist Prof. Ungarn, while someTHING has taken
> over Leigh's brain and influences his actions from within. As you can
> see, this is a pretty far-out tale, a fast-moving and consistently
> mind-blowing one, with a great abundance of pleasing futuristic
> detail.

*Asylum* was also incorporated into one of van Vogt's "fix-up" novels, *Supermind*, but as a novel it doesn't fit with the question.

Answer (score -1):

There's also *The Space Vampires* by Colin Wilson (1976). A rather dire blurb from GoodReads:

> When Captain Carlsen entered the vast derelict spaceship, he was
> stunned by its awesome splendor--and shaken by the discovery of its
> immobilized humanoid passengers.
>
> Later, after three of those strange aliens had been transported to
> Earth, his foreboding was more than justified. The creatures were
> energy vampires whose seductive embraces were total, whose lust for
> vitality was boundless. As they took over the willing bodies of their
> victims and sexual murders spread terror throughout the land, Carlsen
> worked toward their destruction--even though he was erotically drawn
> to the most beautiful vampire of all!

Comment: Famously the source/inspiration for the equally notable movie *Lifeforce*.

Comment: Did you read the question? "It was NOT [. . .], or Colin Wilson's novel *The Space Vampires*.